# Workflow for third party to tag my Lightroom photos

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-catalog

I keep all my photos (terabytes) in Lightroom. A portion of my photos are ready to sell to Getty and they need to have metadata updated based on my notes and someone doing a lot of work.

My virtual assistant lives across the world and does this using this process:

1. I open my computer and screen share
2. The VA does everything while I sleep
3. I kick them off when I need my computer

Is there a better solution where I can hand off these photos to my VA and have them send back the incremental updates? Preferably without the VA having access to my whole computer or even the photos in my catalog they don't need to see?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to export the images to be tagged as a new catalog, send the catalog and images to your VA (or share via some cloud option), have the VA tag them, and then re-import them into your main catalog.

It has limitations, but technically it should work.

You would need to remove the images from your catalog before re-importing them to avoid duplicates, etc.

There are other options (creating smart previews and giving them a copy of your Lightroom catalog, and then overwriting your own catalog when they return it) but they're more at risk of corruption.  I would go with the export catalog option.